# Are there empirical studies that falsify propositions rooted in evolutionary psychology?

Tags: social-psychology, evolution, evolutionary-psychology

Conway III and Schaller (2002, p. 153) argue that "There is a long history of lodging charges of non-falsifiability against evolutionary thinking in the biological  sciences". One of the critics they refer to, is Karl Popper.

Can anyone cite examples of empirical studies that falsify propositions (hypotheses, explanations etc.) rooted in evolutionary psychology, in order to argue against Conway III and Schaller (2002)?

References:

Conway III, L. G., & Schaller, M. (2002). On the verifiability of evolutionary psychological theories: An analysis of the psychology of scientific persuasion. *Personality and social psychology review*, 6(2), 152-166. Link to the article: http://neuron4.psych.ubc.ca/~schaller/528Readings/ConwaySchaller2002.pdf, retrieved 2017, Apr. 11

Comment: What exactly is it that you wish to see refuted in the articles you request? The question is broad and according to your own comments elsewhere this question is more of a probe toward discussion than a specific question.

Comment: Dear @AliceD , many thanks for your question. One the one hand, in my very humble opinion, on this site I have noticed a tendency (I cannot quantify) to reduce psychological questions to the evolutionary paradigm of psychology. While I'm not questioning nor its legitimacy nor its explanation power for certain aspects of human behavior, I believe that it is important to understand its limitations. Moreover, it's important not to over-estimate its usefulness or even its adequacy at understanding human action. -- That is my motivation -- On the other hand, as discussed, I understand that ..

Comment: doing so may be, or rather is off topic within this site. I have realized that fulfilling my motives on this site may cause tensions or at least may not be compatible with the site's goals. Therefore, I have requested to close my account and I'm waiting to do so until I will be sure that another discussion elsewhere on cogsci will not bring about any more comments which I couldn't reply to. Having said this, please allow me to sincerely wish all the best, thanks again for your work.

Comment: Closing your account is not necessary you know. Other questions from you have been received very well. Please feel welcomed.

Comment: @AliceD Why, thank you. I do feel welcome, and there isn't any resentment behind my intention to close my account. Kind regards